# Create query based on inputs from user

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

So lets say I am running a search through the database

```
router.post('/searchLoads', ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
var{ agentCode, loadNumber, pickupNumber, pickupDate } = req.body});
```

The user is not required to fill out all fields.
How would I build a query based on if statements? I was trying something along the lines of

```
result = 'await Load.find({';
    if (agentCode !== undefined){
        result += "agentCode: agentCode, ";
    }
    if(loadNumber !== undefined){
        result += "loadNumber: loadNumber, ";
    }
    if(pickupNumber !== undefined){
        result += "pickupNumber: pickupNumber, ";
    }
    if(pickupDate !== undefined){
        result += "pickupDate: pickupDate, ";
    }
    result += "})";
```

But I am not sure how to then run the code now that I've created the query. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a string, you could create an object.

Assuming we are using ES6+ we can use `agentCode` instead of `agentCode: agentCode` while initializing fields.

```js
var options = {
    agentCode,
    loadNumber,
    pickupNumber,
    pickupDate,
};

result = await Load.find(options);
```

The `!== undefined` checks are not necessary, since `undefined` fields will be dropped.

Comment: This almost gets me there. But when I console log options it outputs          
{
  agentCode: 'JQL',
  loadNumber: '',
  pickupNumber: '',
  pickupDate: '',
  pickupTime: '',
  shipperFacility: '',
  shipperAddress: '',
  shipperCity: '',
  shipperState: '',
  shipperZip: '',
  shipperPhone: '',
  deliveryDate: '',
  deliveryTime: '',
  destinationFacility: '',
  destinationStreetAddress: '',
  destinationCity: '',
  destinationState: '',
  destinationZip: '',
  destinationPhone: '',
  completed: undefined
}
Which then searches the DB for empty strings

Comment: Then I would `console.log(...)` each of the fields you're putting into it. If I had to guess, `console.log(pickupNumber)` would give you ` '', pickupDate: ''` as output. This is likely a problem with your input/HTTP-request

Comment: Even with the inputs disabled on form onsubmit, it still passes an object that searches for

field: undefined

Comment: NVM Just added this 

for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(options)) {
        if(options[key] == undefined){
            delete options[key];
        }
      }

and it worked :D